# Unpack/extract zip file with PHP without relying on any extension

Tags: php, zip, unzip

Is there any way to unpack or extract a zip file with PHP that does not rely on any installed extension? Has anyone written a class or something that can handle it?

Alternatively, is there a solution that uses an extension that is relatively commonly installed on most servers?

I need this to work on as many different servers that I have no control over as possible.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 17):

Check [this lib](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/) it helps to solve same problem

```
require_once('pclzip.lib.php');

$archive = new PclZip(dirname(__FILE__).'/Archive.zip');

if ($archive->extract(PCLZIP_OPT_PATH, dirname(__FILE__).'/extract') == 0) {
    echo "\n error while extract";
} else {
    echo "\n extract ok";
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem, but with this great library, I could unpack my zip files. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like most of them require php.ini settings, which you may be able to override in your script:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_zip.asp

http://devzone.zend.com/article/2105

and here is how to edit the php.ini file without direct access:
http://www.whenpenguinsattack.com/2006/01/20/how-to-override-phpini/